# Perl delete all files in a directory

Tags: perl

How can I delete **all** the files in a directory, (without deleting the directory) in Perl?

My host only allows up to 250,000 "files" and my /tmp folder fills that 250,000 qouta fast with all the session cookies going on. I cannot delete the /tmp folder in this situation. I am only permitted to delete the files within.

**EDIT**:

FTP clients and File managers don't exactly want to open up the folder... I assume it's because of the massive amount of files in it..

Comment: Why do you need Perl to delete files? Isn't `rm` sufficient to do the job?

Comment: What do the session filenames look like?

Comment: @j.w.r random string names "2HU3DO09ASDDQ1L" ect.

Comment: If you are getting `Argument list too long` error use `find` like so: `find /where/ever -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @RedCricket That deletes the folder aswell.

Comment: @Shortland then do this ... `find /where/ever -exec rm -rf {} \; ; mkdir /where/ever` or `cd /where/ever ; find . -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: @RedCricket That would delete and "remake" the folder. As I said I cannot delete it in the first place.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
my $errors;
while ($_ = glob('/tmp/* /tmp/.*')) {
   next if -d $_;
   unlink($_)
      or ++$errors, warn("Can't remove $_: $!");
}

exit(1) if $errors;
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use this. You need to use glob for removing files:

```
unlink glob "'/tmp/*.*'";
```

These extra apostrophes are needed to handle filenames with spaces as one string.

Comment: Won't delete files with no "`.`" in them. Won't delete files with a  leading "`.`". No error reporting.

Comment: On Windows, no need for extra apostrophes ( unlink glob "C:/BECPWIN/Backup/*.*"; )