# Delete all files in a directory, but keep the directory?

Tags: perl, history, delete-file

What's the easiest way to:

- Delete all files in a given directory /files/axis (`unlink`)
- Only files older than 30 days
- The empty directory should remain (do not `rmdir`)

Comment: See existing post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090951/perl-delete-all-files-in-a-directory and this gist: https://gist.github.com/johnhaitas/1507529

Comment: Having written a solution, I'm thinking that you may want to check all files in *and beneath* a given directory. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier way is 'not with perl'.

```
find /files/axis -mtime +30 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do as you ask. It uses `opendir`/`readdir` to list the directory. `stat` fetches all the necessary information, and subsequent `-f _` and `-M _` calls check whether the item is a file and older than thirty days without repeating the `stat` call.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;
no autodie 'unlink';

use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

use constant ROOT => '/path/to/root/directory';

STDOUT->autoflush;

opendir my ($dh), ROOT;

while (readdir $dh) {
  my $fullname = catfile(ROOT, $_);
  stat $fullname;

  if (-f _ and -M _ > 30) {
    unlink $fullname or warn qq<Unable to delete "$fullname": $!\n>;
  }
}
```

---

If you want to delete files *anywhere beneath* a given directory, as I have begun to believe, then you need [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Find). The overall structure isn't very different from my original code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;
no autodie 'unlink';

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ canonpath catfile /;
use File::Find;

use constant ROOT => 'E:\Perl\source';

STDOUT->autoflush;

find(\&wanted, ROOT);

sub wanted {
  my $fullname = canonpath($File::Find::name);
  stat $fullname;

  if (-f _ and -M _ < 3) {
    unlink $fullname or warn qq<Unable to delete "$fullname": $!\n>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Cross Platform Compatible Perl solution, I would recommend either of the following two modules.

1. [`Path::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class)

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Path::Class;

   my $dir = dir('/Users/miller/devel');

   for my $child ( $dir->children ) {
       next if $child->is_dir || ( time - $child->stat->mtime ) < 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
       # unlink $child or die "Can't unlink $child: $!"
       print $child, "\n";
   }
   ```
2. [`Path::Iterator::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule)

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use Path::Iterator::Rule;

   my $dir = '/foo/bar';

   my @matches = Path::Iterator::Rule->new
                                     ->file
                                     ->mtime( '<' . ( time - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 ) )
                                     ->max_depth(1)
                                     ->all($dir);

   print "$_\n" for @matches;
   ```